# Redis Cluster: Find which master holds particular key/slot

Tags: lua, redis

I'm using Redis Cluster, and some keys have a special prefix {foo}, so redis puts them in one slot.

I do this because i want to run some lua scripts against these keys (i can do this if i login to the master as a single instance).

In my setup i have 3 masters, but not sure how to find master which holds slot with my keys {foo}.*

Do you know any way to find master which holds particular key/slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still have to read the entire docs, but already found [this](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial):

> There are 16384 hash slots in Redis Cluster, and to compute what is
>   the hash slot of a given key, we simply *take the CRC16 of the key
>   modulo 16384*.

There is a command for that op already:

http://redis.io/commands/cluster-keyslot

```
>CLUSTER KEYSLOT somekey
11058
```

And to find which slots are there in a server:

http://redis.io/commands/cluster-slots